bluetooth thermal printing from expo react project is stuck with error
im working on a simple react-native project that will support bluetooth thermal printing.
currently trying to configure
januslo / react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer but
while gradlew assemblerelease :
it throws error :
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: C:\Users\BINEESH\Documents\Software_Projects\react-native\printit\node_modules\react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer\android\build\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:2735: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.```



fixed this by following the documentation again.

Try ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
